# Warning: Do not dispose objects multiple times

Tags: .net, vb.net, dispose, using, objectdisposedexception

**EDIT:**

This question is not a duplicate!, maybe is a frequent question the "***what means this warning?***" but is not a duplicate when I'm asking how to fix the warning in a specific code, and I can't by myself even knowing the significate of the warning. –

---

A code analysis in VS shows me this warning:

> CA2202    Do not dispose objects multiple times   Object 'OutputStream' can
>   be disposed more than once in method 'FileSplitter.Split(String, Long,
>   String, String, Boolean, Boolean)'. To avoid generating a
>   System.ObjectDisposedException you should not call Dispose more than
>   one time on an object.: Lines:
>   490   WindowsApplication1 FileSplitter.vb 490

The line `490` is this:

```
End Using ' OutputStream
```

And it gives me the same warning for the other object in the line `498`, this:

```
End Using ' InputStream
```

But I think that I'm using properly the `Using` keywords and I'm not disposing the objects more than once, If I'm doing something wrong then how I can fix my code?

This is the full block:

```
    ' Open the file to start reading bytes.
    Using InputStream As New FileStream(fInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open)

        Using BinaryReader As New BinaryReader(InputStream)

            While (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)

                ' Create the chunk file to Write the bytes.
                Using OutputStream As New FileStream(ChunkFile, FileMode.Create)

                    Using BinaryWriter As New BinaryWriter(OutputStream)

                        ' Read until reached the end-bytes of the input file.
                        While (SizeWritten < ChunkSize) AndAlso (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)
                            ' Some irrelevant code here...

                        End While ' (SizeWritten < ChunkSize) AndAlso (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)

                        OutputStream.Flush()

                    End Using ' BinaryWriter

                End Using ' OutputStream

            End While ' InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length

        End Using ' BinaryReader

    End Using ' InputStream
```

> UPDATE

After adding the try/catch blocks it still showing the same warnings.
If I delete the last try/catch it only shows 1 warning.

```
    ' Open the file to start reading bytes.
    Dim InputStream As Stream = Nothing

    Try

        InputStream = New FileStream(fInfo.FullName, FileMode.Open)
        Using BinaryReader As New BinaryReader(InputStream)

            While (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)

                ' Create the chunk file to Write the bytes.
                Dim OutputStream As Stream = Nothing

                Try
                    OutputStream = New FileStream(ChunkFile, FileMode.Create)
                    Using BinaryWriter As New BinaryWriter(OutputStream)

                        ' Read until reached the end-bytes of the input file.
                        While (SizeWritten < ChunkSize) AndAlso (InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length)

                    End Using ' BinaryWriter

                Catch ex As Exception
                    Throw New Exception(ex.Message)

                Finally
                    If OutputStream IsNot Nothing Then
                        OutputStream.Dispose()
                    End If

                End Try

            End While ' InputStream.Position < InputStream.Length

        End Using ' BinaryReader

    Catch ex As Exception
        Throw New Exception(ex.Message)

    Finally
        If InputStream IsNot Nothing Then
            InputStream.Dispose()
        End If

    End Try
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182334.aspx  the example mimics your code almost exactly

Comment: so, if I understod good, the problem is that the nested inner `using` its using the resource of the other `using`, it means this line?:  `Using BinaryWriter As New BinaryWriter(OutputStream)` ('cause I'm passing it the `outputstream` resource, not?), and then I just only add a try/catch block as explained in the msdn doc?, thanks for the help

Comment: `At the end of the outer using statement, the stream object is released a second time`

Comment: This question is not a duplicate!, maybe is a frequent question the "what means this warning"? but is not a duplicate when I'm asking how to fix the warning in a specific code, and I can't by myself.

Comment: the only danger in ignoring CA2202 is `"Even if Dispose for the object is known to be safely callable multiple times [it is], the implementation might change in the future."`  just add `<SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2202")>` to that procedure to ignore it here.  Aside: dont do `Throw New...` in your catch as that will mess up the call stack of the original exception.  instead just do `Throw`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for this problem is not apparent from your code, but is just knowledge that code analysis has about the objects involved.

Specifically, when you construct an instance of either `BinaryReader` or `BinaryWriter`, you give ownership of the underlying stream over to those objects. Thus, when you dispose of the reader/writer objects, the streams are disposed as well.

As such, when you then go on to dispose of the underlying streams after having disposed of the reader/writer objects, code analysis warns about this.

Now, will this be a problem? No.

Should you fix it? In general, if you enable code analysis, you should fix all errors or warnings unless you have a really good reason not to.

To "correctly" get rid of the issue, it is customary to wrap the outer stream in a try/finally block and only dispose of this is somehow your code reaches the finally block without the reader/writer having been constructed.

In other words, you would only want to dispose of the underlying stream if you didn't actually give ownership of the object to the reader/writer objects.

I think the particular rule also gives an example of how to do this.

Comment: Personally though I might just ask code analysis to shush in this case.

Comment: I've tried to fix the warnings by adding two try/catch blocks in the way that the MSDN example does, but the warnings still appearing on both "Stream.Dispose" instructions, what I'm doing wrong? please could you fix my code?, thankyou for the help